# HotSwap and LWJGL not working in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, lwjgl

I'm trying to get HotSwap to work but I'm not able to get it running.

I have a lwjgl project run by maven and when I change the color of the clear color or even change the string of a System.out.println within the main loop, nothing happens in the application. I have tried to manually reload the classes, they get updated but nothing changes in the actual application.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What Run/Debug Configuration do you use to run the app? Also need more details about how exactly you update (the steps), what you see in IDE interface: does it indicate that the classes were reloaded? See also [Reload modified classes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/altering-the-program-s-execution-flow.html#reload_classes).

Comment: So I change the string in the System.out.println call. Then I hit CTRL+S and then click on "recompile <ClassName>". Then a dialog appears saying "Some classes have been changed. Reload changed classes now?". I hit yes, it says 1 class reloaded at the bottom, but when I switch back to the application, nothing changes. Run/Debug Configuration ist just the default one with the MainClass specified.

Comment: It worked thank you very much!

Comment: @Digot before you post someone else's answer as your own, make sure you understand it, and the question. When someone asks for local holidays, an answer that mixes up holidays, weekdays and workdays is a smoking gun.